# jquery animate to autoheight not working

Tags: jquery, height

update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zQLQV/

I am writing this script to make a content rotator. First, I have all the slides to grab their default height, then they get set to 0 height. On trigger click (uses href with the slide ID), all open slides will go to height 0, and the triggered slide will animate to auto height.

Everything works as planned, excluding the autoheight. All slides remain at 0 height, regardless of the amount of content in them. The only visibility is the min-height of 850.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(function() { 

    $(".slide").each(function() {
        slideHeight = $(this).height();
    });

    $(".slide").css({ "height": "0", "opacity": "0"});


    $(".side-nav ul li a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".slide").stop().animate({"opacity": "0", "height": "0px", "min-height": "0px"}, 100);
        $(currentHref).stop().animate({"opacity":"1", "min-height": "850px", height: slideHeight + "px"}, 450);

    });                     

});
```

Comment: What's the value of the height of the slide prior to being set to 0? If it's less than `850px` min-height will always override it (on browsers that support min/max). [Also, here's a quick jsFiddle outlining scope of OP's needs](http://jsfiddle.net/hYzSy/)

Comment: Could create an example in jsfiddle we could take a look at?

Comment: @Jason Towne please see the fiddle in my comment; should be pretty close to what OP is going for.

Comment: js fiddle has been added: http://jsfiddle.net/zQLQV/

it seems as if its taking the last slide and applying that value to all the slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
$(".slide").each(function() {
    slideHeight = $(this).height();
});
```

What is happening is your `slideHeight` variable was only getting set to whatever the last slide's height was. If you moved the shortest slide to the last spot in the list you'd see the other slides content getting chopped off.

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQLQV/1/) to store each slide's height in a data property within the slide itself.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="side-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one-slide">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two-slide">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three-slide">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="one-slide">asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br></div>
<div class="slide" id="two-slide">asdf<br>asdf<br>asdf<br></div>
<div class="slide" id="three-slide">asdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdf<br></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() { 

$(".slide").each(function() {
    $(this).data('slideHeight', $(this).height());
});

$(".slide").css({ "height": "0", "opacity": "0"});


$(".side-nav ul li a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetContainer = $($(this).attr('href'));
    currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".slide").stop().animate({"opacity": "0", "height": "0px"}, 100);
    targetContainer.stop().animate({"opacity":"1", height: targetContainer.data('slideHeight') + "px"}, 450);
});                        

});​
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been ripping my hair out for hours with this one!